# Action permission Intent not working for alpha testers

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to save user information on google assistant bot with the help of dialogflow using actionpermission intent in my webhook to store user previous details which he/she had filled for the first time. Saving like this works perfectly on my developer account and when i add alpha testers for testing my bot and saving their name and type on google assistant bot it works fine for some testers and parallel its not saving information for some other alpha testers. I don't know why its happening. If anyone can help regarding this issue  it would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is not related to the alpha test but rather to the voice match.

On smart speakers, which are in a multi-user environment, it cannot be assumed by default that the user speaking is always the same. To get around this, smart speakers have a "voice match" feature which needs to be enabled in the device settings.

Until that is enabled, interaction data is not saved between sessions.